# How to convert this map/flatMap into a for comprehension in Scala?

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension

How to convert this map/flatMap into a for comprehension, and please explain how it works, thanks.

```
    def compute2(maybeFoo: Option[Foo]): Option[Int] =
      maybeFoo.flatMap { foo =>
      foo.bar.flatMap { bar =>
          bar.baz.map { baz =>
          baz.compute
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your code can be translated into this:

```
def compute2(maybeFoo: Option[Foo]): Option[Int] =
  for {
    foo <- maybeFoo
    bar <- foo.bar
    baz <- bar.baz
  } yield baz.compute
```

**Quotes from [Programming in Scala, Second Edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed):**

Generally, a for expression is of the form:

```
for ( seq ) yield expr
```

Here, seq is a sequence of generators, definitions, and filters, with semi-colons between successive elements.

This for expression contains one generator, one definition, and one filter:

```
for {
p <- persons // a generator
n = p.name // a definition
if (n startsWith "To") // a filter
} yield n
```

**Translating for expressions with one generator**

First, assume you have a simple for expression:

```
for (x <- expr1) yield expr2
```

where x is a variable. Such an expression is translated to:

```
expr1.map(x => expr2)
```

**Translating for expressions starting with a generator and a filter**

Now, consider for expressions that combine a leading generator with some
other elements. A for expression of the form:

```
for (x <- expr1 if expr2) yield expr3
```

is translated to:

```
expr1 withFilter (x => expr2) map (x => expr3)
```

**Translating for expressions starting with two generators**

The next case handles for expressions that start with two generators, as in:

```
for (x <- expr1; y <- expr2) yield expr3
```

The for expression above is translated to an application of flatMap:

```
expr1.flatMap(x => for (y <- expr2) yield expr3)
```

Comment: ok, I think I get it and in fact, I got that piece of code to work now as well as my next piece     def simpleProgram : Future[Int] = {
      for {
        result <- serviceCall()
      } yield result
    }